# Disable drawer for specific screens

Tags: react-native

I have implement drawer navigator as follows inside that I have stack navigator as follows,

```
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerStyle={{ width: (window.width) * 0.75 }} 
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" children={createHomeStack} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

My stack navigator as follows,

```
createHomeStack = () =>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="LandingPage" component={LandingPage}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="LoginPage" component={LoginPage}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="SignUpPage" component={SignUpPage}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="DashboardPage" component={DashBoardPage}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
     name="OffersPage" component={OffersPage}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
     name="ProfilePage" component={ProfilePage}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

I want to disable drawer for LandingPage, LoginPage ,SignUpPage and enable drawer only rest of screens. Can anyone help me to archive this target ?

Comment: Why not have a separate stack for those screen that you use after authentication and wrap it with a drawer ?

Comment: Yeah that's works perfectly, but one question stack animation won't that way when navigate between two stacks, how can I solve that ?

Comment: you will have to conditionally render the stacks,have a look at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Answer (score -1):

You can add **swipeEnabled=false** to **Drawer.Screen**  by checking your route page

```
<Drawer.Screen
  options={({ route, navigation }) => {
    return {
      swipeEnabled: false,
    };
  }}/>
```

Comment: but this is for all screens not a specific screens

Comment: options={({ route, navigation }) => {
console.log('Route screen',router)
}
}}

you can check your route here and disable it.